# Batch Powershell User csv import and home folder creation

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to use a CSV import to create batch users but for it to also create users' home folder and profile folders but with setting permissions at the same time.

I've found a lot of helpful information online, I just don't know how to make the syntax work with what I already have which took me quite a long time to even get to.

This is my script so far for creating accounts on the domain controller and then syncing them with O365. We use a csv as we create tons of users at the same time:

```
Import-Csv "C:\blablabla\filename.csv" | ForEach-Object { 
New-ADUser -Name $_.Name `
 -GivenName $_."GivenName" `
 -Surname $_."Surname" `
 -DisplayName $_."DisplayName" `
 -SamAccountName  $_."samAccountName" `
 -UserPrincipalName  $_."UserPrincipalName" `
 -Path $_."Path" `
 -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString “Pa$$w0rd” -AsPlainText -force) -Enabled $true `
 -EmailAddress $_."EmailAddress" `
 -ProfilePath $_."ProfilePath" `
 -HomeDrive $_."HomeDrive" `
 -HomeDirectory $_."HomeDirectory" `
 -ScriptPath $_."ScriptPath" `
 -Server $_."Server" `
 -OtherAttributes @{ProxyAddresses= $_."ProxyAddresses"} `
}
Start-ADSyncSyncCycle -PolicyType Initial
```

All the values point to columns in the excel file which auto-complete based on a user's first and last name.

I know I'm supposed to be creating the home and profile folders and setting permissions as per the below for example, I just don't know how to make the syntax work with what I already have?

So far, the values only get set in AD correctly but the folders don't get created and permissions aren't getting applied.

I guess I could just add an other command to create a new folder but I wouldn't know how to do append that to the foreach command?

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path \\dc\userdata
$ACL = (Get-ACL -Path $HomeDirectory)
$FullControlAccessRule = (New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]"hcc.local\$UserName","FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"))
$ACL.AddAccessRule($FullControlAccessRule)
Set-ACL -Path $HomeDirectory $ACL
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

So, as per what NAS said, something like this then

```
?

 -OtherAttributes @{ProxyAddresses= $_."ProxyAddresses"}
 New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $_.HomeDirectory           
 New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $_.ProfilePath             
 $ACL = (Get-ACL -Path $_.HomeDirectory)                       
 $FullControlAccessRule = (New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
                                [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]"hcc.local\$($_.samAccountName)",        
                                "FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"))
    $ACL.AddAccessRule($FullControlAccessRule)
    Set-ACL -Path $_.HomeDirectory $ACL
 $ACL = (Get-ACL -Path $_.ProfilePath)                       
 $FullControlAccessRule = (New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
                                [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]"hcc.local\$($_.samAccountName)",        
                                "FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"))
    $ACL.AddAccessRule($FullControlAccessRule)
    Set-ACL -Path $_.ProfilePath $ACL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Import-Csv "C:\blablabla\filename.csv" | ForEach-Object { 
    New-ADUser -Name $_.Name `
     ...
     -OtherAttributes @{ProxyAddresses= $_."ProxyAddresses"}      # Remove backtick
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $_.HomeDirectory           # create home path if needed
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $_.ProfilePath             # create profile path if needed
    $ACL = (Get-ACL -Path $_.HomeDirectory)                       # No need for quotes around properties if they do not contain spaces or other special characters
    $FullControlAccessRule = (New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(
                                [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]"hcc.local\$($_.samAccountName)",        # replace $UserName with correct variable
                                "FullControl", "ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"))
    $ACL.AddAccessRule($FullControlAccessRule)
    Set-ACL -Path $_.HomeDirectory $ACL
    # ->                                                                     # repeat for profile path if needed
}
```

Comment: Hello there, thank you so much for that, will the hcc.local\$($_.samAccountName)" bit automatically take the username from the above or do I have to manually feed it? Effectively what I'm trying to achieve is for it to do all of this by itself as per the values that it gets from the csv. Also, how do I repeat this for profile paths if needed? I'm just a slightly confused. All users from the csv will need their profile paths and home drives created and assigned and have the drive letter assigned for the home directory and so on.
Thank you so much for your time!

Comment: I'd like to also add the following commands after the script (I already have an automated way to connect to Office365) but don't know how to make the email addresses pull in from above, or, even how to set this part to happen recursively for each user. Any thoughts?
I will post the commands I'm trying to append below

Comment: Set-MsolUserLicense -UserPrincipalName "@domain.com" -AddLicenses "domain:STANDARDPACK"
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity newuser@domain.com -User 'admin@domain.com' -AccessRight FullAccess -InheritanceType All -Automapping $false
Add-MailboxFolderPermission -Identity newuser@domain.com:\calendar -user admin@domain.com -AccessRights Editor


Any thoughts?

Comment: To repeat for the profile path, copy the acl part of the code (from `$ACL=...` till `Set-ACL -Path...`) and replace the variable `$_.HomeDirectory` with `$_.ProfilePath`

Comment: For your second comment, probably better to create a new question

Comment: OK, I think I've got it, but, I can't post the whole code here for you to check if it's right. I have edited the initial question as I don't have enough characters here...
I do have to say, stackoverflow is rather annoying to use as it's so hard to write back and respond...

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful, all that remains now is to actually test this so as to ensure that it works. Thanks!

Comment: I just tested it, and it seems to work fine except for my home drive gets mapped as Z instead of P which I specified in the csv file and which does get set in AD yet when I log into the user the drive is Z? Also, for some reason, the initial password I'm defining in as plaintext in the script doesn't seem to work at all when I first try to log in, weird, don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: I checked and there's nothing else mapped as P on that drive, and, weirdly, in AD it still says that the home drive letter is P yet while logged in it's mapped as Z?

Comment: The dollar signs in your password are powershell special characters (they indicate the beginning of a variable). Try escaping them with backticks, like ``"Pa`$`$w0rd"`` or use single quotes around the password string `'Pa$$w0rd'` which prevents powershell for looking for variables and treat that part as a string.

Comment: For the drive letter you should use an uppercase character followed by a colon

Comment: you were absolutely right, both suggestions worked, thank you so much!!!

Comment: uhm, for some reason, I'm getting two profile folders created for each user, is that because the csv import already specifies a profile folder? Maybe in that case I only need to set permissions, but not necessarily create the new folder? The same doesn't happen for the home folder so I guess that's all fine.